# Mock built-in objects with NightmareJS

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, electron, nightmare

I am trying use NightmareJS to load a page, click a button, then take a screenshot to test. The click handler on the button requests the geolocation. This is part of what I'm testing for. I want the page to appear a certain way if the user grants the geolocation permission, and another way if they decline.

The problem is that Nightmare doesn't expose a method for me to intercept the permission prompt to accept or decline it. After some research I learned that Electron just hardcodes this permission to 'granted' so there may not even be a way to set it to declined.

What I'd like to do is replace Electron's `navigator.geolocation` object with a mock that responds to the geolocation request in a certain way.

```
new Nightmare().goto('https://example.com')
    .evaluate(function () {
        navigator.geolocation = {
            getCurrentPosition(cb) {
                cb({coords: latitude: 42, longitude: -42});
            }
        }
    })
    .click('#locateMe')
    .screenshot()
    .end()
    .then(diffScreenshot)
```

However when I try this it seems like the navigator.geolocation object doesn't change. Is there some other way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is possible (or should be) in both projects, you might try changing:

```
navigator.geolocation
```

To

```
window.navigator.geolocation
```

This is because most evaluate calls are run in a clean context, or so I think. If this doesn't work then Navalia might be able to do it as it's fairly "bare-metal" so-to-speak.

Best of luck!

Comment: Using window.navigator seems to have worked! Thanks!